# how to programmatically add the items to SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have SharePoint document library. How to programmatically add the items to SharePoint document library?

Comment: I am using client object model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this *** [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65557/programmatically-add-item-to-sharepoint-list-from-window-application) *** for the reference.

And the Other *** [link](http://sampathnarsingam.blogspot.in/2012/10/programmatically-upload-document-using.html) *** also might help you...

This two link might have your answers.
And let me know this helped you or not.